# Как использовать CURL в приложении windows form C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, curl, c++-cli

Пытаюсь работать с библиотекой С++ curl в проекте windows form C++

```
 CURL *curl;
    CURLcode result;
    //инициализируем curl
    curl = curl_easy_init();
```

На строчке  `curl = curl_easy_init();` начинаются ошибки, как будто не подключён lib. В windows form как то иначе подключаются lib компоненты? Подключал через программу и настройки проекта не помогло. 
visual studio 2010 C++/

> 1>CurlFormTest.obj : error LNK2031: не удалось создать P или Invoke для "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z); в метаданных отсутствует соглашение о вызовах
>
> 1>CurlFormTest.obj : error LNK2028: ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00001A) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z) в функции "int __clrcall main(cli::array^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

Когда ответили на мой вопрос всё получилось, но когда снова столкнулся с такой проблемой забыл как исправить и почитал вновь ответ сложно было найти нужную настройку потому решил для себя и других сделать графическую подсказку, вот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
После настройки curl работает. Внимание для Debug и Ralase Наставать нужно отдельно. По моему лучше сразу выбрать realase

Comment: По поводу курла не скажу, но в .NET взамен можно использовать классы `WebClient`, `WebRequest`, `HttpClient`, а также библиотеку RestSharp.

Comment: Перед использованием надо сначала вызвать `curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)`, и посмотреть, не вернет ли она ошибку.

Comment: 1>CurlFormTest.obj : error LNK2031: не удалось создать P или Invoke для "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z); в метаданных отсутствует соглашение о вызовах
1>CurlFormTest.obj : error LNK2028: ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00001A) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z) в функции "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В проектах С++/CLI, компилируемых с параметром [`/clr:pure`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation?view=vs-2017) или `/clr:safe` соглашение вызова по умолчанию - [clrcall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/clrcall?view=vs-2017), а не cdecl. Поэтому библиотеки, у которых в заголовочных файлах в объявлении функций не прописано явно соглашение вызова (но подразумевается cdecl), не заработают. Вам нужно либо компилировать с параметром `/clr` (без pure/safe), либо задекларировать все нужные функции CURL вручную.

См. [Linker Tools Error LNK2031](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2031?view=vs-2017)

Comment: а где указывать при компиляции библиотеки /clr (без pure/safe)

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка В свойствах проекта, General (Общие) - Common Language Runtime Support (Поддержка общеязыковой среды выполнения)

Comment: К сложению после этих действий кюрл просто не компилировался

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Вы его из исходников собираете или как DLL подключаете? Какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: из исходников предо ставленых на официальном сайте. Чуть позже еще раз попробую и отпишу что за ошыбка.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Ну просто в вопросе у вас написано, что вы lib подключаете. Это как бы подразумевает, что вы с бинарниками работаете. Может скинете весь проект на файлообменник, чтобы проще было понять, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Я с исходников компилирую lib і dll

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка В том проекте, в котором вы собираете curl из исходников, конечно не нужно устанавливать параметр `/clr`(в нем вообще ничего менять не надо, верните в последнее состояние, в котором он компилировался). Я имел в виду, нужно этот параметр установить в проекте win forms, который его использует.

Comment: Щас попробую так

Comment: Инициализация  прошла думаю будет работать. А с openGl так тоже можна?

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Думаю да, в С++/CLI можно использовать все, что можно использовать в обычном С++.

Comment: Дуже вам вдячний Запрацювало